# observer fire action to early. before action is initialize observes fired the action

Tags: ember.js

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
   {{input type="text" value=model.name}}
  </ul>
  <p {{action 'test'}}>test</p>
</script>
```

ember code

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
// put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return Ember.Object.create({name:'dilip'});
  },
  actions:{
    test:function(){
        alert('route test');
        console.log('test')
  }
}
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  handleChange:function()
  {
    console.log('handle')
    this.send('test')

  }.observes('model.name')
})
```

action 'test' is already defined in route but its showing below error.This error comes only when i am using observes.

Error while loading route: Error: Nothing handled the action 'test'.

Comment: I just hit this one. It seems that the observes fires at a point in which the controller is not prepared to send actions to the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observer does fires before the route is ready to handle the action. This kinda, sorta makes sense because the controller is "built" as part of the route. I've solved this by setting a property within the routes `setupController` hook to let the controller know that it's ready for action!

```
// Route
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('routeIsReadyForAction', true);
}

// Controller
routeIsReadyForAction: false,

someObserver: function() {
    if (!this.get('routeIsReadyForAction')) {
        return;
    }

    this.send('someRouteAction');
}.observes('someProperty'),
```

Comment: Hey @dilip. If you liked my answer do you mind accepting it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the action in the controller, not in the route. Check out this jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yubowi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You should define your action within controller.

`this.send('test')` Looks for actions in this extended class (in this case controller). If u make this.sendAction('test') It goes out and looks for actions but these have to be predefined like so `actionName="actionName". This is mostly used when you have a component that needs to interact with a controller

```
{{my-component actionName="actionName"}} < sendAction now looks for controllers action
```

Comment: actually problem is here that observer observes while first time data loads.It shoud observe when data changes.

Comment: observe model.hasDirtyAttributes.

Comment: you error says Nothing handled the action 'test'.. So its not about the observer, there is no such action in given controller. Duh.

Comment: i am not using ember data here.